# jQUery chosen which files to include for using it

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

i am new to chosen.js .i download release 1.0.0 . when i download it contains a lot of file .in which i think we have to include chosen.min.css and chosen.jquery.min.js in our html page.i am confirming my assumption is correct or not ?? or we have to include other files also in our html page to run chosen method properly ??

Comment: you have to include .js and .css file and don't change the location of other files :)

Comment: there are a lot of files .i think i can remove some files at least index.html,index.proto.html,options.html ??any other that we can remove ??

Comment: well, i think you can open the .js file, take a look at it and see where these other files are being used :)

Comment: is there any cdn for chosen  ??